# Use of reserved words in SQL statement in field value

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am running an update sql statement that is returned a bad request error. This is only happening when I'm using reserved words for the field value. I know this happens for table and column names and how to account for that but I've never had this with the actual value. How do you account for this?

Comment: For example? Can you post an example of what you mean so we can try and understand exactly what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `Parametrized queries` in place of `inline queries` to easily resolve this.